# Create a new bootable ubuntu installation disk with a working PC running Windows 10

Tags: boot, system-installation

I have an old PC that was running Ubuntu 17.04 (EOL) and a PC nearby that is using Windows 10. I want to make a USB stick that can be used to install a new version of Ubuntu without damaging my PC with Windows. I want to load the new OS on my old PC that used to run Ubuntu 17.04. I keep running into problems requiring the forgotten passwords on the old system. Is this possible? I can access the internet to download a bootable image, but do not know how to proceed from that point.

My questions are

1. Where can I download a bootable installation image?
2. How do I load the bootable image on a USB stick on the spare PC USB drive?
3. How can I install the  new Ubuntu system to replace the old (EOL) Ubuntu on the old system with the new stick?

Answer (score 4):

> Where can I download a bootable installation image?

- https://releases.ubuntu.com/ - I would recommend the newest LTS version, 20.04.3 LTS, and depending on the hardware standard Ubuntu Desktop or Kubuntu if a fairly powerful computer, or a light-weight community flavour, Lubuntu ubuntu MATE or Xubuntu if weak or old hardware. You may also consider the other flavours, Ubuntu Budgie, Ubuntu Kylin and Ubuntu Studio.

> How do I load the bootable image on a USB stick on the spare PC USB drive?

- In Windows you can use [Rufus](https://rufus.ie)

> How can I install the new Ubuntu system to replace the old (EOL) Ubuntu on the old system with the new stick?

- If you back up your personal files (documents, pictures, music etc) to another disk, you can let the installer use the whole drive (and overwrite the whole old system). This is straightforward and easy.
- If you want to keep your personal files and settings, you can keep the home directory and make it into a home partition, and then prepare a suitable partition table with file systems for the new system. This is a bit risky, so you had better backup your personal files (documents, pictures, music etc) to another disk anyway (before you start editing the partition table and installing).

You can find instructions via these links:

- https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview
- https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview